# Replicate CSS3 Text Arrange/Fly-In

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to replicate the CSS text fly in from this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZpZ1zRcR6c&t=537s

However, when I run my code, it results in the letters being transformed but stationary. The letters are placed randomly, but they don't fly to their inline-block display. I am trying to do this all dynamically within a function, so it may be a bit confusing. I'm not sure what I have done wrong here...

```
  var congratsPhrases = ["Awesome!", "Wonderful!", "Great Job!", "Fantastic!", "Terrific!", "Superb!", "Amazing!", "Brilliant!", "Well Done!", "Excellent!", "Nice Work!", "Bravo!", "Perfect!", "Genius!"];

function congratulateUser(){

  // empty body, background color black, pick a random congratulatory message
  $("body").empty();
  $("body").css({"background-color":"black"}).append(`<ul class="text-animate hidden" id="congratsUL"></ul>`);
  var congratsInd = Math.floor(Math.random()*congratsPhrases.length);
  var randomCongratsMessage = congratsPhrases[congratsInd];

  // CSS transition
  $("#congratsUL").css({"position":"absolute", "top":"50%", "left":"50%", "list-style-type":"none", "transform":"translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)"});
  for (var i = 0; i < randomCongratsMessage.length; i++) {
    $("#congratsUL").append(`<li>${randomCongratsMessage[i]}</li>`);
    $("#congratsUL li").css({"color":"white", "margin-right":"30px", "opacity":"1", "display":"inline-block", "font-size":"3.5em", "font-family":"'Bungee Shade', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial", "transition":"all 2.5s ease"});

    $("#congratsUL li:last-child").css({"margin-right":"0"});
    // get random number between 1 & 300 that is either positive or negative
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*250) + 1;
    randomNum *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) === 1 ? 1 : -1;
    // position the li elements on the page randomly
    $(`#congratsUL.hidden li:nth-child(${i+1})`).css({"transform":`translateX(${randomNum}px) translateY(${randomNum}px)`, "opacity":"0"});
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#congratsUL").removeClass("hidden")
  }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the CSS inline, so when you remove the `hidden` class from the `ul`, the inline styles for the `lis` still exist. You can override the inline styling using `!important` in the CSS:

```js
var congratsPhrases = ["Awesome!", "Wonderful!", "Great Job!", "Fantastic!", "Terrific!", "Superb!", "Amazing!", "Brilliant!", "Well Done!", "Excellent!", "Nice Work!", "Bravo!", "Perfect!", "Genius!"];

function congratulateUser(){

  // empty body, background color black, pick a random congratulatory message
  $("body").empty();
  $("body").css({"background-color":"black"}).append(`<ul class="text-animate hidden" id="congratsUL"></ul>`);
  var congratsInd = Math.floor(Math.random()*congratsPhrases.length);
  var randomCongratsMessage = congratsPhrases[congratsInd];

  // CSS transition
  $("#congratsUL").css({"position":"absolute", "top":"50%", "left":"50%", "list-style-type":"none", "transform":"translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)"});
  for (var i = 0; i < randomCongratsMessage.length; i++) {
    $("#congratsUL").append(`<li>${randomCongratsMessage[i]}</li>`);
    $("#congratsUL li").css({"color":"white", "margin-right":"30px", "opacity":"0", "display":"inline-block", "font-size":"3.5em", "font-family":"'Bungee Shade', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial", "transition":"all 2.5s ease"});

    $("#congratsUL li:last-child").css({"margin-right":"0"});
    // get random number between 1 & 300 that is either positive or negative
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*250) + 1;
    randomNum *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) === 1 ? 1 : -1;
    // position the li elements on the page randomly
    $(`#congratsUL.hidden li:nth-child(${i+1})`).css({"transform":`translateX(${randomNum}px) translateY(${randomNum}px)`});
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#congratsUL").removeClass("hidden")
  }, 500);
}

congratulateUser();
```

```css
ul:not(.hidden) li {
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;
    opacity:1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you could just clear out the inline styling on `timeout` instead of removing the class of the `ul`:

```js
var congratsPhrases = ["Awesome!", "Wonderful!", "Great Job!", "Fantastic!", "Terrific!", "Superb!", "Amazing!", "Brilliant!", "Well Done!", "Excellent!", "Nice Work!", "Bravo!", "Perfect!", "Genius!"];

function congratulateUser(){

  // empty body, background color black, pick a random congratulatory message
  $("body").empty();
  $("body").css({"background-color":"black"}).append(`<ul class="text-animate" id="congratsUL"></ul>`);
  var congratsInd = Math.floor(Math.random()*congratsPhrases.length);
  var randomCongratsMessage = congratsPhrases[congratsInd];

  // CSS transition
  $("#congratsUL").css({"position":"absolute", "top":"50%", "left":"50%", "list-style-type":"none", "transform":"translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)"});
  for (var i = 0; i < randomCongratsMessage.length; i++) {
    $("#congratsUL").append(`<li>${randomCongratsMessage[i]}</li>`);

    $("#congratsUL li:last-child").css({"margin-right":"0"});
    // get random number between 1 & 300 that is either positive or negative
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*250) + 1;
    randomNum *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) === 1 ? 1 : -1;
    // position the li elements on the page randomly
    $(`#congratsUL li:nth-child(${i+1})`).css({"transform":`translateX(${randomNum}px) translateY(${randomNum}px)`, "opacity":"0"});
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#congratsUL li").attr("style","");
  }, 500);
}

congratulateUser();
```

```css
#congratsUL li {
  color:white;
  margin-right:30px;
  opacity:1;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:3.5em;
  font-family:'Bungee Shade', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica, Arial';
  transition:all 2.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```